# Create a component Holder

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive

How can I create a component that acts as a list but the list length and content is depending on the child component specified within the component holder.

example :

```
<parent-component>
  <child-component> content </child-component>
  <child-component> content </child-component>
  <child-component> content </child-component>
  <child-component> content </child-component>
  <child-component> content </child-component>
</parent-component>
```

if you are familiar with angular material, the result desired is the same as the MatStepperComponent.

**Note: the content in each child-component has a completely different model from the other. so basically, injecting components instead of data model**

Comment: IE: if you have a list of 10 things, you want to have 10 child into your parent component NOT hardly coded?

Comment: exactly what i need. like the children need to be dynamic

Comment: Just as a clarification to the previous comment. the children need to be also defined through HTML

Comment: I'll make you a simple stack blitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind this question was to create a component which wraps a number of child component, and, depending on their number the wrapper becomes a list.

**Question :** why would I implement such a thing ?

**Answer :** Imagine you want to create something like a stepper.

```
<stepper>
  <step> <component-a> </step>
  <step> <component-b> </step>
  <step> <component-c> </step>
</stepper>
```

the solution I came to get to is as follow

**StepComponent**

**step.htm**

```
<ng-template>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

**step-component.ts**

```
@ViewChild(TemplateRef)
public stepContainerRef: TemplateRef<any>;

constructor() {
}

ngOnInit() {
}
```

**StepperComponent**

**stepper.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let step of steps; let elementIndex = index">
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="step.stepContainerRef"></ng-container>
</div>
```

**stepper-component.ts**

```
 @ContentChildren(StepComponent) steps: QueryList<StepComponent> = new QueryList<StepComponent>();
```

And *le tour est joué*.

for more details and understanding please refer to the following links:

- [ng-content: The hidden doc](https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/ng-content-the-hidden-docs-96a29d70d11b)
- [angular: ng-template, ng-container, ngtemplateoutlet](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/)

Answer (score 1):

You can iteare the data you get in an `ngFor`.

Here's a simple logic. For this example, this is the kind of data I'm using:

```
[{
        "name": "John",
        "age": 30,
        "role": "Actor"
    },
    {
        "name": "Elys",
        "age": 22,
        "role": "The main one"
    },
  {
    "name": "Jhon",
    "age": 44,
    "role": "a random role"
  }
]
```

the (fake) service that retrieve the data:

```
    import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable()
    export class MainService{

    private data = [{
            "name": "John",
            "age": 30,
            "role": "Actor"
        },
        {
            "name": "Elys",
            "age": 22,
            "role": "The main one"
        },
      {
        "name": "Jhon",
        "age": 44,
        "role": "a random role"
      }
    ]
      constructor(){}
      public getData(){
        return this.data;
      }
    }

The main component: 

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { ChildComponent } from './child.component'
import { MainService } from './main.service'
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  data: any;
  constructor(private service: MainService){
    this.data = this.service.getData();
  }
}
<h2>The list above is created dinamically

  <hr>

  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data">
    <child-cmp [data]="item"></child-cmp>
    <br>
  </ng-container>
```

the child component

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-cmp',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html'
})
export class ChildComponent  {
  @Input() data: any;
}
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row">
  <span style="margin-right: 10px"> {{data.name}}</span>
  <span style="margin-right: 10px"> {{data.age}}</span>
  <span style="margin-right: 10px"> {{data.role}}</span>
</div>
```

**Note** I've used `ng-container` for the iteration because angular doesn't render it.

Working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2svnpt

Comment: I agree this is when you have a template child component. the main question is how would you approach the problem if you need to inject for examples different forms.

Note : the forms don't have the same model

Comment: Well, your speech is kinda generic, sadly. But, for example, you can create, inside every single child component, it's html struct with another `ngFor` based on a `Field` array on its`@Input`. The same logic that I've used to iterate the first data, just changed a bit in order to be even more abstract.

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear enough. I updated the description after reading your answer.